# How to get rid of strange .jar files in "User Entries" of Run Configurations -> ClassPath

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to use log4j to save log files. I have gotten it to work if I create a new Java project and have `log4j-1.2.17.jar`, `slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar` and `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar` on my build path. Let's call this `ProjectA`.

I have another project called `ProjectB` which has these three `jar` files on buildpath (so far the same as `ProjectA`), exception this `ProjectB` *also*has `ProjectC` on its build path. This doesn't seem to change anything, except when I go into the `Run Configurations` (Eclipse) of any main method in `ProjectB`, it'll now have `logback-classic-0.9.28.jar` on its so-called User Entries of the ClassPath.

This ruins my logging because it says `SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is true you cannot have more than one slf4j related log files in your class path.

Either you remove that project c from class path
 or else
Remove those slf4j jars from class path because indirectly those are added through projectC.

Main thing is there should not be double slf4j related jar files in you class path.

Comment: The issue i'm facing is that I don't know how to remove the `logback-classic-0.9.28.jar`. There's no delete button and it's not in my lib folder

Comment: Rightclick on your java project. From BuildPath>Configure Build Path you will see a dialog box there will be Library tab. Go to that tab you will be able to see all added jar you can select that jar and click remove button.

Comment: It's not in my buildpath, hence the question. Only in Run Configurations!

Answer (score 0):

In your launch configuration, remove the classpath entirely, then rebuild it by adding the required projects, *without their exported entries*, then the other individual jars or class folders that you need. This way, you can configure the classpath for the launch configuration, exactly the way you want it.